# how can implement Backward scheduling in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can i create backward scheduling using TSQL. In my old system i have something like this. Is it possible to implement the same logic using TSQL?

**Field Name: `A-NEST BY`**

and here is the formula for `A-NEST BY`. note [A-CUT BY] is a date field

> IF(weekday(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7)) = 7, datesub(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7),1),
>   if(weekday(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7)) = 1, datesub(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7),2),
>   datesub(A-CUT BY, 7)))

[A-CUT BY] is calculated date field which on the first line here `IF(weekday(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7)) = 7, datesub(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7),1),`   if the date is 7 thge seventh date or Saturday moves the schedule to Friday. if sunday or 1 move the schedule to Monday

**weekday(date) or weekday(date,format):**

Returns the day of week of a date. The second input is optional, but if given must be one of "number",
"name", or "abbrev". If "number" or omitted, the result will be a number, with 1 for Sunday, 2 for
Monday, up to 7 for Saturday. If "name", the result will be the word Sunday, Monday, etc. If "abbrev",
the result will be the word Sun, Mon, etc.

**datesub(date, N)or datesub(date, N,unit):**

Subtracts N days from date, that is, returns the date N days before the input date. If N is negative, it
will return the date N days after the input date. The third input is optional; if provided, it must be one of
years, months, days, hours, or minutes. If not provided, days will be assumed.

Comment: What is "A-CUT BY"??? The code you have posted here is not valid t-sql.

Comment: my old system is called Trackvia online cloud database `A-CUT BY` is a date. the code is not sql code it just to show the logic

Comment: And what is "A-CUT BY"? Some explanation of what this is attempting to do would go a long way to getting an answer.

Comment: A-CUT BY is calculated date field. if the date is 7 or saturday moves the schedule to Friday

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @ [A-CUT BY] is calculated date field which for example on this code `IF(weekday(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7)) = 7, datesub(datesub(A-CUT BY, 7),1),`   if the date is  seventh date or Saturday moves the schedule to Friday. if Sunday or 1 move the schedule to Monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am totally guessing here because this question lacks any clarity. I think you just want to use a case expression. Here is an example of what I think you might want.

```
set datefirst 7 --Sunday

declare @ACUTBY datetime = getdate()

select 
case datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY)
    when 1 then 2
    when 7 then 5
    else datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY)
end as [A-CUT BY]
```

--EDIT--

SqlZim made an excellent suggestion to add datefirst to avoid any issues if using another language or the first day of the week is changed for whatever reason.

You can read more about DATEFIRST here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql

Comment: Thank you, thats what i would like to achieve but i tried it as `declare @ACUTBY datetime = getdate()+3

select 
case datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY)
    when 1 then 2
    when 7 then 5
    else @ACUTBY
end as [A-CUT BY]`  returns Tuesday `2017-04-03` rather than Monday `2017-03-03` the date adjustment only if sunday or saturday

Comment: you awesome @SeanLange

Comment: gj interpreting all that. Bonus round for `set datefirst 1`? -- j/k